# Как связать Fragment и DialogFragment в MVP

Tags: android, mvp, dialogfragment

Есть `MainFragment`, который содержит описание товара. Если пользователь хочет добавить комментарий к товару, то он делает это в `DialogFragment`(открытом из `MainFragment`) и потом комментарий передается в `MainFragment`.

Насколько я понял, при MVP для обоих фрагментов нужен свой `Presenter`, но я не понимаю, как правильно наладить связь между ними, чтобы `DialogPresenter` для `DialogFragment` передал комментарий в `MainPresenter` для `MainFragment`.

Можно ли передавать `MainPresenter` в конструкторе для `DialogFragment` или передавать его через интерфейс, чтобы `DialogPresenter` мог к нему обратиться или есть какой-то другой, правильный путь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если рассматривать диалоговое окно как самостоятельное `View`, то лучше создать для него отдельный `Presenter`. А, модель пусть будет та же самая.

Если используете LiveData, то при изменении комментария в диалоговом окне, данные автоматически обновятся и в основном `View`.

Как-то так...

Comment: Поправьте, если я неправильно понял. Мне надо создать модель в главном фрагменте и передать ее в диалог, откуда уже я помещаю эту модель в `Presenter` для диалога. И при этом `Presenter`'ы для каждого `View` не должны между собой общаться?

Comment: По хорошему, Вам нужно передать в диалог только id товара, а MVP стек диалога (если так можно сказать) вытащит из БД модель и обновит её в БД при изменении комментария.